# If I enter URL manually or refresh the page the component will not render reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs. I just started with react router. In app.js routing work if I enter the path manually or refresh the page. the same routing in login component will not work if I enter the path manually or refresh the page. I dont know whether it is correct way of doing or not.For better understanding I have pasted my code below  Please help me

thank you

App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './layout/header/index.js';
import Footer from './layout/footer/footer';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home/index';
import Login from './components/Login/index';
import Notfound from './components/notFound'

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
       <div>
         <Header></Header>

         <Switch>
           <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
           <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
           <Route component={Notfound} />
         </Switch>

         <Footer></Footer>
      </div>

    </Router>

  );
}

export default App;
```

login.js component

```
import React from 'react';
import image from '../../logos/banner.png';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import Login from './login';
import Signup from './signup';

class login extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="container loginBody">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-10 mx-auto">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-lg-6">
                                <img className="loginImage" alt="" src={image} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-lg-6">
                                <Router>
                                    <Switch>
                                        <Route path="/login" component={Login}></Route>
                                        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup}></Route>
                                    </Switch>
                                </Router>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default login;
```

package.json

```
"name": "mfrontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
```

Comment: How are you serving the app? You may have to look into configuring "push-state routing" on whatever server you're using.

Comment: I am using localhost:3000

Comment: That's not nearly enough information. What's serving requests on that port? Give a [mre].

Comment: Sorry I don't know what Information I should provide. Just yesterday I have started reactjs.

Comment: npm start for serving the app

Comment: And what script does `npm start` run? What's in the `package.json`? Are you using Create React App/`react-scripts`, for example? There are lots of ways to write and run a React app, we can't debug without an example. [Edit] the question to provide enough information for someone else to recreate the problem.

Comment: I am using create-react-app and my package.json  code I have pasted in my question

Comment: If that was true, `npm start` would fail with a parsing error. Please put a bit more effort in. Create a new app with the simplest possible code to recreate the problem.

Comment: thanks for helping I am getting only warnings not any error while starting the server

Comment: Therefore we can conclude that's *not* the content of your `package.json`. I see no point in interacting further until there's a proper [mre] in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Switch` will render the first component that matches the `path` but it won't traverse down and try to match a child `Route` unless it matches the first `Switch` `path` prop from `App`.

Move all of your routes to `App` component and remove them from the `Login` component

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route component={Notfound} />
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying I tried that one but I want to display that component in that particular div. If i used like this the component is loading full page

Comment: @matheenulla You can extract the wrapper to a different component and use it inside `Login` and `Signup`

Comment: @matheenulla You can also do it like this but it will require the path to be something like `auth/login` `auth/signup`